# Proving that this right triangle $ABC$ is isosceles

Tags: geometry

Having sides of lengths $a, b$ and hypotenuse $c$, show that if $\sin(A)=\sqrt{a/(2b)}$, then the triangle $ABC$ is isosceles.
Here's a picture:

[image: hello]

The only things I can think of is that $\sin A=a/c$ and the  pythagorean theorem but I don't know where to start. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(A) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$? Your version does not hold in general, only if $b = 1$.

Comment: Pythagoras tells you that $c = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ hence $\sin A = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Comment: I've corrected the mistake

Comment: $a/c = \sqrt{a/2b}$. Square both sides. You get $(a-b)^2 = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sin^2 A=\frac{a^2}{c^2} =\frac{a}{2b}\to c^2=2ab$$

by Pithagoras,

$$c^2=a^2+b^2$$

can you finish?

Comment: I've corrected my mistake

Comment: @Rewind: Please, check if can finish it

Comment: can you explain a little more how exactly you find that a and b are equal

Comment: @Rewind, $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Comment: oh I understand now thanks !